# Parse.com Send a push notification with query restriction on installation field via REST API

Tags: push-notification, parse-platform

I'm trying to send push notifications (at 12 PM the next day) to installations whose "updatedAt" field is not older than two days. Here's the code:

```
var two_days_ago_date = new Date()
two_days_ago_date.setDate(two_days_ago_date.getDate() - 2)

var push_time = new Date()
push_time.setDate(push_time.getDate() + 1)
push_time.setHours(12)
push_time.setMinutes(00)
push_time = push_time.toISOString()
push_time = push_time.substring(0, push_time.length - 1)

Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "X-Parse-Application-Id": "XXX",
    "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "XXX",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: {
    "where":{
        "appVersion":"1.4",
        "updatedAt" : {"$gte" : two_days_ago_date}
    },
    "push_time": push_time,
    "data": {
        "alert":"",
        "sound": ""
    }
 },
 url: "https://api.parse.com/1/push"
}).then(function() {
  console.log("Successful push");
}, function(error) {
  console.log(error);
})
```

If I remove the restriction the code works fine, otherwise not.

Comment: What doesn't work? Does the push get not sent at all? Do you see an error message? Please be more specific :-)

Comment: No error. The push is scheduled but not delivered. It's a [local push](http://blog.parse.com/2012/11/14/local-push-because-its-5-oclock-somewhere/). Basically if I remove this line it works: `"updatedAt" : {"$gte" : two_days_ago_date}`